# Prevent abstract environment to reset pagenumbering

Tags: titles, page-numbering, abstract

I use  `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}` for my thesis.
I have three parts, each with an abstract.
Whenever I put an abstract, the page numbering resets to 1.
I would like to continue with the numbering it had before placing the abstract.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Introduction}

 Introduccion

\part{Part 1}
\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}

Part1

\part{part 2}
\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}

Part2

\part{3}
\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Thorsten: It is best to provide a link to the [minimal working example (MWE) post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on the Meta site, especially for new users. See also the [Text building blocks](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) thread.

Comment: @Juan: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can (and should) edit your original question to add such information. I copied it to it for you now.

Comment: @Juan: If you add `@username` into your comments then that user is notified about it.

Answer (score 11):

It depends on the option of the class `titlepage`. The default setting is `titlepage=true`. 
You can do two things:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
```

Or redefine abstract:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
  \else
    \small
    \begin{center}%
      {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
  \fi}
  {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Your first suggestion works fine `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,notitlepage]{report}` but I get numbering on the title page too. The second option `\makeatletter
\@titlepagefalse
\makeatother` does not work for me.

Comment: I changed my answer. Sorry

Comment: Could you please explain what the `notitlepage` option does?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever With this option you decide whether the environment `titlepage` is used or not`. The environment starts a new page and end this page. It also put in onecolumn mode whether you are working with twocolumn or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch the `titlepage` environment. `abstract` uses `titlepage` (if the class option `titlepage` is set, which it seemingly is for the report class) and `titlepage` sets the page counter to 1 (in `\begin` *and* `\end`).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\titlepage}{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}     {}{\PackageError{titlepage}{failed to patch \string\begin{titlepage} to not reset the page counter}{}}
\patchcmd{\endtitlepage}{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}  {}{\PackageError{titlepage}{failed to patch \string\end{titlepage} to not reset the page counter}{}}
\makeatother
```

See `\show\abstract` and `\show\titlepage`.