# Page number is reset to 0 with \include command

Tags: page-numbering, include

I am writing a lengthy document that I have divided in chapters. Each chapter is in a separate file which is called from the master file by means of the command `\include`.

The problem is that every time an `\included` file starts the page number is reset to 1. Of course, I can control it inserting manually  `\setcounter{page}{number}` at the beginning of each chapter, but I must be doing something wrong.
Any idea of why this is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: then there is something wrong with your setting or you have a command like `setcounter{page}{0}` elsewhere. It is _not_ the default that the page number is reset

Comment: Could you provide a few more details, ideally in the form of a MWE? Quite often, the process of forming a MWE will help to debug the problem. Please include the `documentclass` and any important packages.

Comment: The obvious place to look would be near the top of each included file. It could be that you made a template file for each with a `setcounter` in and later filled in the content.

Comment: I added this in the top of the included files in order to remove the word "chapter" and the numbers attached to it:\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\chapter{Notas sobre la edición y la traducción}
Could the problem lay there?

Comment: Maybe you have something like `\counterwithin{page}{chapter}` or `\@addtoreset{page}{chapter}`? Best would be to make a MWE (see cmhuges comment). BTW: If you don't want chapter (and section and subsection …) numbers, you should try `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` at the document preamble. If only chapter shouldn't have a number, you may e.g. try a KOMA-Script class and either `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}` at your preamble or replace `\chapter{…}` by `\addchap{…}`. Maybe you should ask another question for this (if search does not already offers one).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want numbered chapters it's not as complex as you seem to think:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

in the preamble is all that's needed and a chapter can start as, for instance,

```
\chapter{Notas sobre la edición y la traducción}
```

As already pointed out in the comments, there's no way that `\include` resets the page number by itself, unless you have loaded some package that implements page numbering by chapters or have given a command such as

```
\numberwithin{page}{chapter}
```

In this case it's not `\include` that resets the page number, but `\chapter`, because LaTeX has been requested to do so.

Check if in your preamble `page` is mentioned and take the appropriate action, that is deleting the instruction.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and as suggested by @qubyte in his comment, the problem was at the top of included files. Specifically each included file had it's own abstract and by default the abstract environment resets page numbering.

The solutions given in this answer solved the problem by redefining the abstract:
[Prevent abstract environment to reset pagenumbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17892/42367)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `\input` instead of `\include`. You can begin each sub-file with a `\chapter` and it would work perfectly. I did the same with my MS thesis.