# How to avoid numbering the first page of the document?

Tags: page-numbering

I have two sections before the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{First random title} \lipsum[1]
\section*{Second random title} \lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\section{First section} \lipsum[3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4]
\section{Last section} Wombat \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

The problem is, that LaTeX starts the page numbering on the first page and I don't want that. I want the page numbering to start after the table of contents. How can I do this?

Comment: A Minimal working example please.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the horizontal bar at the top by issuing the following: \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} ?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`\pagenumbering` can be helpful in removing page numbers *and* resetting it, at the same time. The following minimal example, using the `article` document class, removes the page numbers until the ToC, and then starts it again at 1 (set using `\arabic`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{First random title} \lipsum[1]
\section*{Second random title} \lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic page numbers (and reset to 1)
\tableofcontents
\section{First section} \lipsum[3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

`\pagenumbering{gobble}` sets the "page number printing macro" to `\@gobble`, which eats its argument/contents. `\pagenumbering{arabic}` resets this to `\arabic{page}`.

The principle holds for other (standard) document classes as well.

Comment: This however can cause problem when `hyperref` is used.

Comment: There is one problem left. Between the last section and the table of contents, I get one blank page with a horizontal bar at the top. The horizontal bar comes from fancyhdr. How can I clear also fancyhdr styles before the table of contents? See: http://i49.tinypic.com/23mvg3t.jpg

Comment: @Chris: Use `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` to remove the header rule, and `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}` to re-insert it. If this doesn't solve your problem completely, please update your original post with a [complete, minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764).

Comment: @egreg: So how can this be done if the `hyperref` package is used? I'm using that package and I'm getting the warning `destination with the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again>`...

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Use `\pagenumbering{Alph}`, for instance, and `\pagestyle{empty}` for the duration.

Comment: @egreg: I'm already using `\thispagestyle{fancy}` to enable the functionality in the `fancyhdr` package, so I guess using `\pagestyle{empty}` as well would be a bad idea?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Please make a followup question

Comment: @egreg: I solved it, thanks. I figured `\pagestyle{empty}` had to be used just in order not to display the page number (which is still actually there when using `\pagenumbering{Alph}`) — this is effectively achieved when using `\thispagestyle{fancy}`. However, I found that the `titlepage` environment automatically resets the page number when it ends, which leads to a collision in the page number which in turn generates a warning when using the `hyperref` package. So in my case the solution was to not use the `titlepage` environment (In fact, I don't know why I would actually need it).

Comment: I also found that the `abstract`-environment reset the page number, so I had to redefine it not to (see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17887/prevent-abstract-environment-to-reset-pagenumbering/17892#17892)).

Comment: The original solution in the post works perfectly fine for me, using hyperref...

Comment: The Adobe reader will still think page 1 is actual page 1.

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}` is necessary and may be used without `gobble`.