# How to stop page numbering from resetting for each chapter

Tags: chapters, page-numbering

How can I stop LaTeX from resetting page numbers whenever a new chapter starts? I would like to have a single global page number for the whole report. I don't think I am changing the default page numbering in any way with what I have in my preamble, but just in case, here it is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%use a new bibliography for each chapter
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}  

%math environment
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

%graphics environment
\usepackage{graphicx}

%allow figure captions to cross between pages
\usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{adja-page}{\\#1 #2 }

% reset figure numbers between chapters
\usepackage{chngcntr}
 \counterwithin{figure}{chapter}

% flush all floats whenever a new (sub(sub))section start
\usepackage{placeins}
\let\Oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection}
\let\Oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsection}
\let\Oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsubsection}

%double spaced
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

%smaller margins
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}

%define display style for large operators in rational equations
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
\newcommand\bfrac[2]{\left(\frac{ #1}{ #2}\right)}


%define a chapter author environment
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\centering\parindent0pt\vspace*{0pt}%
  #1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{25pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\makeatother

%no header
\pagestyle{plain}

%make bibliographies single spaced
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}

%include sub(sub(sub)))sections in TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}



\begin{document}
\include{title}
\tableofcontents
\vfill
\newpage
\include{intro}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}
\end{document}
```

Within each \included file, I have something like this:

```
\chapter{chap1}
\chapterauthor{author list}
\begin{abstract}
bla bla
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
bla bla
...
```

One of the includes has this in its entirety, and it resets page numbers:

```
\chapter{title}
\cite{Merchant2010}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bib}
```

Comment: There is not a single chapter in there ...

Comment: It's all between the \begin{document} and \end{document} - each chapter is in a separate file and is simply included. I will edit shortly with detail from one of them. @ChristianHupfer edited.

Comment: Nothing in the code you show resets pages numbers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's what I thought. And yet the document I produce restarts page numbers for every chapter...

Comment: Well I wrote "the code you show". Probably the problem is in the part you didn't show. As long as you hide things inside \include we can't help you.

Comment: Is there `\pagenumbering{arabic}` in the includes?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer there really is nothing relevant in the includes. Just \chapters, \sections, \subsections\, \bibliographies. Definitely no \pagenumberings. I'm wondering if maybe something internal to the sectionbib environment causes this? I have edited to show the entirety of one of the includes.

Comment: you make it hard for anyone to answer as you have not provided an example that anyone can run to see the problem.

Comment: Put two \chapter{blub} directly after \begin{document}. If the second resets the page number you have a minimal example. If not you know that something later is the culprit.

Comment: OK, I will work on that. Please bear with me for a few minutes.

Comment: To make a test file you should not need `\include` (just put the content of a small dummy chapter directly in your main document, and you should be able to delete most of the packages, for example do you really need `graphicx` or `placeins` to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: The problem is the `abstract`. In the `report` class, `abstract` resets the page number and you have an abstract for every chapter.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger thank you. Is there a way to change that behavior? EDIT: this seems relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17887/prevent-abstract-environment-to-reset-pagenumbering

Comment: Yes, the solution is to add the notitlepage option to the report class as discussed in that question I linked.