# Page numbering resets with every new chapter

Tags: chapters, page-numbering, report

This is my first time posting so if my formatting is off, I'm more than happy to be corrected! I'm also far from a TeX expert, so please forgive my questionable terminology.

I'm trying to write a dissertation using the NotesTeX package in the report document class. Each time I make a new chapter, the page numbering resets to 1. Any ideas on why this might be the case and how to resolve it? Notably, I've attempted to follow both the solutions given in the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17887/prevent-abstract-environment-to-reset-pagenumbering), as well as the discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422810/how-to-stop-page-numbering-from-resetting-for-each-chapter?noredirect=1&lq=1) with no success - After doing everything advised in the linked posts, the page numbering issues persisted.

I suspect, therefore, that this problem is related to the NotesTeX package. Here is an MWE:

```
\pdfminorversion=4\relax
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0\relax
\RequirePackage{pdf14}

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{marginnote,sidenotes,fancyhdr,titlesec,geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{NotesTeX}
\usepackage{tikz,physics,cancel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,mathrsfs}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\abstract{Abstract}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\clearpage\section{Section 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.1}

\clearpage\chapter{Chapter 2}
\clearpage\section{Section 2.1}

\end{document}
```

I hope I haven't produced a dupe, and many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NotesTeX.sty` has

```
% Footer and header of the body
% the command ``\pagestyle{myplain}'' must be inserted
% just after ``\begin{document}''
\newcommand\ps@myplain{
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand\@oddfoot{\hfill-- \thepage\ --\hfill}
\renewcommand\@oddhead{}}
\let\ps@plain=\ps@myplain
```

which means that every chapter (which does `\thispagestyle{plain}` runs `\pagenumbering{arabic}` so resets the counter. that looks like a bug.

I know nothing about that package if you need to use it you may want to make a local copy and remove the line

```
    \let\ps@plain=\ps@myplain
```

Comment: Thank you! Removing that line solves the numbering issue - however, now the page numbers on a new chapter page appear differently to those in later pages. For instance, see page 1 and 3 vs 2 and 4 in the MWE with this modification. Any thoughts on how to handle that?

Comment: The package has also 52 lines like `\newcommand{\bfa}{{\bf a}}`. `:-(`

Comment: @FH93 perhaps you would prefer to put that `\let` back but remove the line `\pagenumbering{arabic}` instead

Comment: One could redefine `\ps@myplain` without `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perfect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @egreg Do you suggest removing those lines? I initially included them due to a suggestion from my physics colleagues who wanted those shortcuts. If there are cumbersome, then let me know and I can update the package in the second release!

Comment: @Aditya Well, `\bf a` has been deprecated for more than 20 years.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I'll remove these in the next update.

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of the NotesTeX package. I've known about this bug for a while. There are two issues which contribute to this bug which I have written about below.

First, let me simplify your MWE (there are a few packages which are repeated and may cause overwrite conflicts):

```
\pdfminorversion=4\relax
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0\relax
\RequirePackage{pdf14}

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{NotesTeX}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\abstract{Abstract}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\clearpage\section{Section 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.1}
\clearpage\chapter{Chapter 2}
\clearpage\section{Section 2.1}

\end{document}
```

I've removed most of the \usepackage{} as most packages you listed are included in NotesTeX. Now onto the actual issue;

1. Firstly, the chapter heading is not configured in NotesTeX when using the **article** class. That is on me, I'll need to update it and I'll get right on it!
2. Secondly, and most importantly, **the report class is the root of the page numbering conflict.** NotesTeX was built on the Jheppub style and both are configured to work with the **article** class. Making NotesTeX/Jheppub work with other classes is a tougher challenge.

My suggestion, if you are not attached to the report style, is to use the article class and use **part** instead of chapter.