# Prevent the equation counter from resetting with every new chapter

Tags: equations, enumerate, chapters, counters, roman-numerals

I usually enumerate my propositions, definitions etc. with (Hindu-)Arabic numerals (e.g. Definition 1.1.1., Proposition 1.1.2., Theorem 2.1.1. etc.). I would hence like to enumerate my equations with a single Roman numeral with a non-resetting counter, so as not to confound the two.

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{equation}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{equation}
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}


\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{equation}
1 + 2 = 3.
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

As is, both equations are labelled (I).

How can I adjust my code, so as to prevent the equation counter from resetting with every new chapter?

I am aware of the existence of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17887/prevent-abstract-environment-to-reset-pagenumbering). It does not answer my question, as it pertains to abstracts specficially.

Comment: Did you try adding `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}` to your preamble?

Comment: Assuming your TeX distribution is reasonably up to date, you should be able to achieve your formatting objective by issuing the instruction `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}` *before* running `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{equation}}`.

Comment: @Mico Even better, `\counterwithout*{equation}{chapter}` can go anywhere.

Comment: @Bernard That worked admirably.